# Derivative of the exponential function (of matrix functions) by a strange integral and a function object which does not commute with its derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, exponential-function, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

At the bottom of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_map) section of an article, Wikipedia claims:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\exp(X(t))=\int_0^1\exp(\alpha X(t))\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\exp((1-\alpha)X(t))\,d\alpha$$

For any general $t$-dependent object $X$. I can't get access to the paper they referenced from. My attempts to find this are as follows:

When $X(t)$ commutes with $\frac{d}{dt}X(t)$ the result of that integral is trivially what would be expected from the chain rule. When $X$ does not commute however, there is a problem! I let $\Delta$ denote the object, be it a matrix (what I'm most interested in) or something else, representing the direction derivative of $X$.

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\exp(X(t))&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{d}{dt}\frac{(X(t)^n)}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d}{dt}(X(t)^n)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(X+h\Delta)^n-X^n}{h}\cdot\frac{dX(t)}{dt}
\\\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(X+h\Delta)^n-X^n}{h}&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(\Delta X^{n-1}+X\Delta X^{n-2}+X^2\Delta X^{n-3}+\cdots)+o(h^2)}{h}
\\&=\Delta X^{n-1}+X\Delta X^{n-2}+\cdots
\\&=\sum_{\alpha=0}^{n-1}X^{\alpha}\Delta X^{n-(1+\alpha)}
\\\therefore\frac{d}{dt}\exp(X(t))&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\sum_{\alpha=0}^{n-1}X^{\alpha}\Delta X^{n-(1+\alpha)}\cdot\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\end{align}$$

And I have no idea whether any of this is right, nor how to make my "$\Delta$" anything meaningful (I would assume it is $\frac{d(X(t))}{dt}$, but I don't know). I don't even know if it should *be* in the above calculations. I more importantly have no idea how to calculate the integral formula at the top of this question or turn my workings into an integral, and I've just been showing my failed attempts thus far.

I would greatly appreciate any references, hints or answers, as this seems like a very important (at the very least interesting) formula but not one that I will be able to solve with my own knowledge.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please name the Wikipedia reference you are referring to.

Comment: @HandeBruijn [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_map) one; at the bottom of this section

Comment: This is a good and important question, an excellent exercise needed in some important cases in geometry, for instance when $X$ is of the shape $X=\nabla^2$, the curvature on some geometric space, and we can use $\nabla=\nabla_t$, a deformation family for a given connection $\nabla$ on the space. The (exponential) functional calculus in $X=\nabla_t^2$ may provide a good  way to exhibit special characteristic classes... +1

Comment: @dan_fulea a good question maybe but an even better answer - I do not even understand the comment you just made. One day, perhaps... +1 to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will write simply $X$ instead of $X(t)$, and let $Y=X'$ be the derivative. Then by the linearity of the product function $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)\to X_1X_2\dots X_n$ in each of the components, we have explicitly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I'=(X^0)'&=0\ ,\\
(X^1)'&=Y\ ,\\
(X^2)'&=YX+XY\ ,\\
(X^3)'&=YXX+XYX+XXY\ ,\\
(X^4)'&=YXXX+XXYX+XYXX+XXXY\ ,\\
\\[2mm]
&\qquad\text{ and in general...}
\\[2mm]
(\ X^{n+1}\ )' 
&=YX^n+XYX^{n-1}+\dots+X^nY
=\sum_{\substack{j,k\ge 0\\j+k=n}}X^jYX^k\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then we have, using $a$ instead of $\alpha$, and $b:=1-a$ to have an easy notation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 e^{aX}\; Y\; e^{bX}\; da\
&\ =
\int_0^1 
\left(\sum_{j\ge 0}\frac 1{j!}a^jX^j\right)
\; Y\; 
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac 1{k!}b^kX^k\right)\; da\\
&\ =
\int_0^1 
\sum_{n\ge 0}
\sum_{\substack{j,k\ge 0\\j+k=n}}
\frac 1{j!k!}a^jb^k \; X^j\;  Y\; X^k 
\; da\\
&\ =
\sum_{n\ge 0}
\int_0^1 
\sum_{\substack{j,k\ge 0\\j+k=n}}
\frac 1{j!k!}a^jb^k \; X^j\;  Y\; X^k 
\; da\\
&\ =
\sum_{n\ge 0}
\sum_{\substack{j,k\ge 0\\j+k=n}}
\frac 1{j!k!} \; X^j\;  Y\; X^k 
\underbrace{\left(\int_0^1 a^jb^k\; da\right)}_{=B(j+1,k+1)}\\
&\ =
\sum_{n\ge 0}
\sum_{\substack{j,k\ge 0\\j+k=n}}
\frac 1{(n+1)!} \; X^j\;  Y\; X^k 
\\
&\ =
\sum_{n\ge 0}
\frac 1{(n+1)!} \; \Big(\ X^{n+1}\ \Big)' 
\\
&\ =
\left(
\sum_{n\ge 0}
\frac 1{(n+1)!} \; X^{n+1}\right)'
\\
&\ =(e^X-I)' 
\\
&\ =(e^X)' 
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Above, $B$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), and for $j,k$ with $j+k=n$...
$$
B(j+1,k+1)=\frac{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma((j+1)+(k+1))}
=\frac{j!\; k!}{(j+k+1)!}=\frac{j!\; k!}{(n+1)!}\ .
$$
At many places we have exchanged two "limit-like" operation (like integration, derivation, building a series). At these places we have a "domination" in norm by the corresponding functions
obtained by replacing $X,Y$ by the real numbers $\|X\|,\|Y\|\ge 0$,the
so exchanging the operations reduce to exchanging them in the world of functions of a real variable $x=\|X\|\ge 0$, which is more or less standard. Versions of the Dominated Convergence Theorem (Lebesgue) can be applied directly on more general spaces, Banach spaces.

---

*Later EDIT:* The above solution focuses on the "algebraic" aspect of the computations. Here is an explanation for the "analytic" aspect, first of all for the need of being rigorous on this point, because this was a main concern in the OP. The analytic aspect is best seen in the following step, where we (write explicitly more lines to) exchange two "limiting" operators:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac 1{n!}X^n\right)'(t)
&=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac 1h\left[
\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac 1{n!}X^n(t+h)\right)
-
\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac 1{n!}X^n(t)\right)
\right]
\\
&=
\color{blue}{\lim_{h\to 0}}
\color{darkgreen}{\sum_{n\ge 0}}
\frac 1{n!}\frac 1h
\left(X^n(t+h) - X^n(t)\right)
\\
&\overset{\color{red}{(?)}}=
\color{darkgreen}{\sum_{n\ge 0}}
\color{blue}{\lim_{h\to 0}}
\frac 1{n!}\frac 1h
\left(X^n(t+h) - X^n(t)\right)
\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac 1{n!}(X^n)'(t)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
There is a point that has to be addressed at least above, namely the point where we exchange the order of the the two "limiting proceses" $
\color{blue}{\lim_{h\to 0}}$ and $
\color{darkgreen}{\sum_{n\ge 0}}$.
(A simple counterexample is as follows. Consider the double sequence $(a_{kn})_{k,n\ge 0}$ displayed as an infinite matrix. It has a "diagonal", and now put under the diagonal only zeros, and over it only ones (or even some random numbers to have no limit below). Then building limits first on rows, then on columns delivers one answer, taking the limits in the other order - an other answer...)

How to obtain this exchange by using the [Dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) in the form $\lim_h\int_S f_h=\int_S f$ where $f_h\to f$ and $\|f_h\|$ is dominated by one and the same function $g$?

Take the ("discrete") measure space $S$ to be the set of the natural numbers, where each $m$ gets the measure $1$. Now fix some $t$ and consider $f_h$ to be the function on $S$ given by $f_h(m)=\frac 1{m!}\cdot \frac 1h(
X^m(t+h)-X^m(t))$. Seen as a function in $h$, we have continuity and the limit for $h\to 0$ exists, it is in the above notations $\frac 1{m!}(X^{m-1}Y+\dots +YX^{m-1})(t)$, so in norm it is estimated as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\|\frac 1{m!}(X^{m-1}Y+\dots +YX^{m-1})(t)\right\|
&\le 
\frac 1{m!}(
\|X^{m-1}Y+\dots +YX^{m-1}\|)(t)
\\
&\le
\frac 1{m!}(
\|X^{m-1}Y\|+\dots + \|YX^{m-1}\|)(t)
\\
&\le
\frac 1{m!}(
\|X^{m-1}\|\;\|Y\|+\dots + \|Y\|\;\|X^{m-1}\|)(t)
\\
&\le \frac 1{m!}\cdot m\;\|X\|^{m-1}(t)\;\|Y\|(t)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, under conditions like having a $\mathcal C^1$-class function $X$, tacitly considered in such cases, the above is bounded by $g:S\to\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, where $g(m)=
\frac 1{m!}\cdot m\;\|X\|^{m-1}\;\|Y\|$.
Then for $h$ in a small compact neighbourhood of $0$ the whole family $f_h$ is (by (uniform) continuity) in norm bounded by $2g$. So the domination is realized by $2g$, which is in $L^1(S)$ because $\int_S 2g=
2\sum_{m\ge 1}\frac 1{m!}\cdot m\;\|X\|^{m-1}\;\|Y\|
=2\|Y\|\;\exp\|X\|<\infty$.

The other exchange of limiting processes,
$
\color{blue}{\int_0^1}
\color{darkgreen}{\sum_{n\ge 0}}
=
\color{darkgreen}{\sum_{n\ge 0}}
\color{blue}{\int_0^1}
$
is covered in a similar way.

Comment: Incredible answer! I'll award the bounty once I understand what you mean by the footnote on dominated convergence. My untrained eye read your proof and spotted no dubious manipulations that need further justification. You used only the linearity of the integral operator (thus being allowed to swap order of summation and integration) and then you just took everything not dependent on $a$ out of the integral w.r.t $a$... I don't see where the domination-norm explanation is needed. For context, I don't know the dominated convergence theorem or anything much about Lebesgue theory

Comment: Some details regarding the analysis involved were added, the argument assumes that $X$ is a function of class $\mathcal C^1$, i.e. differentiable with a continuous $X'=:Y$. (Here $X$ takes values in some space of matrices, or in some Banach space).

Comment: thank you for the further explanation! Answer accepted

Comment: Great introduction to this kind of theory! Two naïve quibbles: why is the final sum not equal to $2\|Y\|\exp(\|X\|)$? Where’d the two go? And second minor question: I’ve seen the $L(S)$ notation before but I don’t know what it is called or what it means.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the good eye, yes, the final two is missing, i'm editing it! The $L^1$ space is the space of all integrable functions, in our case, for some function $h:S=\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ it means that $\int_S|h|=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}|h(n)|<\infty$.

Comment: Is the $L^$ notation the integral equivalent of the $C^n$ notation? So $L^n(S)$ means the function is $n$ times integrable in the space $S$?

Comment: No, for the $L^p$-spaces the link is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space, here there is no geometry, we are in the world of measure theory, a world containing the probability theory, functions here have to only be "integrable". The $L^p$-spaces have as an underlying set some set without restrictions. The $\mathcal C^n$-spaces are defined only in relation with some open sets in some $\Bbb  R^k$...

Comment: Oh - I thought a function was $C^n$ if it was $n$ times continuously differentiable @dan_fulea