# Integral of exponential of a matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $A$ is an operator on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, or a matrix. I can define:
$$e^{tA} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}t^{n}A^{n}$$
Can I integrate it? For instance, does:
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{t A}dt = \int_{0}^{1}dt \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}t^{n}A^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}t^{n+1}A^{n}$$
hold? In the above I obviously exchanged the sum with the integral, but have no idea how to justify it in the context of operators.

Comment: You may be interested in @dan_fulea ‘s excellent answer to my post, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214237/815585)

Comment: That final sum shouldn't have $t^{n+1}$ in it.

Comment: Show the series converges uniformly for $t \in [0,1]$, according to the operator norm.

Comment: Yes, you can integrate it. It is known as Bochner Integration, and the integration and summation are interchanged by Fubini's theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is justified, either by Fubini's theorem, or simply by noting that the series converges uniformly for $t \in [0, 1]$. After all, $e^{tA}$ is just a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, so $\int_{0}^{1}e^{tA}\,dt$ is by definition $n \times n$ scalar integrals. Hence pretty much all theorems of scalar integration apply without any extra effort needed to prove them.

In contrast, if $A$ was an operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, then there is the subtlety of defining integration of such operator valued functions to make sense of the integral.