# How to find the Fréchet derivative of a matrix exponential?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, frechet-derivative, matrix-analysis

> Let $f : \Bbb R^{n\times n} \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ be the matrix exponential $$ f(A) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!} $$ Let $B$ be a matrix that commutes with $A$. Show that the value of Fréchet derivative $J_{f,A}: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ of $f$ at arbitrary point $A$, evaluated at $B$ is given by $$ J_{f,A}(B) = Be^{A} $$

---

If $B$ does not commute with $A$, the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) is $$ \int_0^1 {e^{(1-s)A}B{e^{sA}}} \,{\rm d}s $$ How can I prove it?

Comment: One nice trick is to use $\exp(A)\approx (I+A/n)^n$ for $n$ large enough, so that the derivative can be computed via product rule as $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(I+A/n)^{n-j}(B/n)(I+A/n)^{j-1}$, which can be interpreted as Riemann sum.

Comment: Where does this come from? From a book? From lecture notes?

Comment: How can you feed a matrix to $J_{f,A}: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and obtain a matrix?

Comment: Hey! I asked exactly this question a while ago! Let me find the link

Comment: See [this great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214237) by @dan_fulea